# The number of ways to put numbers in squares

Tags: combinatorics

If  one put the numbers from $1$ to $7$ in the squares in stead of letters in which the sum of cells is in descending order like shown in the figure .Every number should  be used once or twice or never .Also the order of numbers in every oblique row its sum appear always in descending order.

In how many way one can do that ?

[image]

Comment: HINT: Count them. Brute force. Post your answer when done.

Comment: By descending, do you mean $a\gt b \gt c \gt d$? or in the other order?  Is equality permitted?  And $c \gt x \gt z$?

Comment: @Ross Millikan Yes !

Comment: "Also the order of numbers in every oblique row its sum appear always in descending order." I do not understand this. Please give a concise formulation of what you mean.

Comment: This is a cute little problem. It's saddening that the OP didn't give it a try to solve it on his own, and that he even didn't manage (or wasn't willing) to put it into decent wording.

Comment: An answer to this question has been deleted by a moderator and my vote for it transferred to another answer. Why?

Answer (score 3):

If the inequalities are strict, $Cxy$ can only be $431$ or $521$  Starting with $521$, we must have $b=6, A=7$ and $AbCD$ fails.  So we must have $Cxy=431$.  Then $cxz=432$ or $531$  If it is $531$ we must have $abcd=7651$, but then $A=7$ and again $AbCD$ fails.  If $b=6, A=7$ and again $AbCD$ fails, so $b=5$.  Then $a=7, d=3$ and we can have either $A=7,D=1$ or $A=6, D=2$, giving two solutions.  $$\begin {array}{c c c} A & 7 & 6 \\ a & 7& 7\\b & 5 & 5 \\c&4&4\\C&4&4\\d&3&3\\D&1&2\\x&3&3\\y&1&1\\z&2&2\end {array}$$